# Extract road defects from terrestrial LiDAR, in Erdas 2012 or ArcGIS10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, lidar, erdas-imagine, feature-extraction

I'd like to extract road defects from a lidar point cloud. So, wherever a road surface drops or raises by a few mm relative to 100 cm around it.

I know it's possible but I just can't find or figure out a workflow for it.

[Erdas Webinars](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/archive/webinars/2012_05_02%20Maximize%20Your%20LiDAR%20Investment%20with%20ERDAS%20IMAGINE.wmv) has the workflow for version 2011, but this is very different in 2013 as it uses a raster .img file instead. I also looked at the workflow files from Imagine Help.

In [ESRI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/LAS_dataset_3D_view/015w00000040000000/) it's a similar issue.

Any advise on workflows for this? We own both software so I would like to manually extract defects from a terrestrial LiDAR scan using either of these.

Comment: What features are you attempting to extract? I have seen models (ERDAS and ESRI/python) that extract tree points and forest polygons.

Comment: Road defects...so wherever a road surface drops or raises by a few mm relative to 100cm around it.

Comment: Is your data a point cloud or is it a derivative, such as a DEM, TIN, or other DSM?

Comment: @Barbarossa it is a point cloud but we also have the derivative products including xyz plus DEM,TIN and DSM

Comment: Did you every come up with a solution? I need to do something similar to extract manhole covers.

Comment: @MikeRads sorry no. Its 2+ years on now though so there is probably an Esri workflow or try globalmapper